# How to construct an image from VarBinary(Max), change its type and store to a physical location

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, filestream, memorystream

Could please anyone tell me how I can construct an image from (DB) VarBinary(Max) data type column in C#. Also I do want to change its type and save it to a physical path on my hard drive.

So many people has posted answers to similar sort of questions but I couldn't find an appropriate answer which fits my above criteria.

Anyone's help will really be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: Show code on retrieval please? Do you have the image as a byte[]?

Comment: byte[] imagedata = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Data"] as byte[]; // Data is the VarBinary(max) type data column. The stored image type in DB is JPEG and I want to convert it to the PNG before saving to the physical path.

Comment: Assuming you want to save a jpg as c:\img.jpg, try :         using(var fs = new FileStream("c:\\img.jpg",FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(imageData,0,imageData.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }

Comment: no jbl. I want to convert a jpg image to png and than want to save this image to a physical path.

Comment: You may want to investigate the FileStream data type in SQL Server 2008 (if you run that version): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First turn your byte[] to a Bitmap:

```
    // Turn the binary into an image
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
    Bitmap myImage = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(imagedata );
```

Then save to disk:

```
     myImage.save("file.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Any issues let me know, this works for me.

Edit: You'll need using System.ComponentModel; at the top.

Edit2: Copy the bitmap to a new bitmap if you get the GDI error:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(myImage);
myImage.Dispose();
myImage = null;
bm.save("file.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I am getting an error of "A generic error occurred in GDI+" while saving the image

Comment: Odd I didn't have a problem. I put a second edit in which should resolve it.

Comment: still no different. I even tried with using statement as some people say you have to make sure the file is not in use of any where else while you trying to save it. but no difference

Comment: Edited again, see if that's any use. Seems like a common error, but I don't get it here.

Comment: This error is because of rights issue. I have changed the path to the existing Images folder of my asp.net test application and it is working fine. Instead of using TypeConverter I have used MemorySteam. I am going to post my solution for others.

Answer (score 0):

Following is my answer to constructing an image from Byte[] and changing its data type to a different format.

```
            byte[] imagedata = dt.Rows[0]["Data"] as byte[];


        System.Drawing.Image newImage;
        if (imagedata != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imagedata))
            {
                newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                newImage.Save("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\TestPictureConversion\\WebApplication2\\WebApplication2\\Images\\Test Image.png");
            }
        }
```

As I have changed the path to the Images folder inside my application and now it is not producing "A generic error occurred in GDI+" error anymore.
To avoid getting "A generic error occurred in GDI+", either change the rights to the folder or select a location which has the read/write rights on your network.

Kind Regards